# Filter dataset on JOIN based on other table value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join

I am using Entity Framework. I have 2 tables: `Unit` and `Message`. They look like that:

```
public class Unit
{
    int id;
    DateTime date;
}

public class Message
{
    int id;
    int unitId;
    DateTime date;
}
```

I want to join every `Unit` for every `Message`.

I do something like that:

```
DateTime from = DateTime.Now;

 db.Unit.Join(
    db.Message.Where(m => m.date >= from),
    u => u.id,
    s => s.unitId,
    (u, s) => new 
    {
        MessageTime = s.date,
        UnitTime = u.date
    }
)
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(r => new 
    {
        MessageTime = MessageTime,
        UnitTime = UnitTime
    }
)
.ToList()
```

The `Unit` class contains `date` which I want to use when doing the join. I only want to take the messages from `Message` which has `date` >= `unit.date`. I know that I can do `.Where(x => x.UnitTime >= x.MessageTime)`, but I do not want to make the join and filter after that.

Is it possible to filter based on the other table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ supports only equijoins. In case you need different type of join, you can replace `Join` with `SelectMany` + `Where` - EF is smart enough to convert it to SQL `INNER JOIN`:

```
db.Unit.SelectMany(
    u => db.Message.Where(m => u.id == m.unitId && m.date >= u.date && m.date >= from),
    (u, m) => new
    {
        MessageTime = m.date,
        UnitTime = u.date
    }
)
```